# What are the default programs/apps/tools in a windows 10 home edition that auto update

Tags: windows-10, auto-updates

I own a Dell Inspiron 5559 laptop with Windows 10 Home edition. I wanted a list of programs that automatically update themselves in the background so that I can disable them.

Till now I have identified(and disabled) the following,

- Windows update(via registry)
- McAfee AV(although I agree this is not a default program)
- Dell update
- Windows store setting for auto updating apps

Are there any other?

The reason I want to disable these background update mechanisms is that I do not have the best internet connection and they drain my bandwidth.

I recognize the importance of keeping your system up to date which is why I make it a point to manually update all of the above mentioned items on a weekend(as planned) instead of it happening automatically.

Additionally, I am just looking for a list and not the actual steps to disable corresponding updates(those I'll search myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are disabling Windows Update there should no other Software(except for Windows Store) which updates themselves. The Windows Updater & Windows Store are the only "Apps"//"Software" who would be updating something(except for your own software)